# Python Operation % not working?

Tags: python, python-requests, operation

I cant seem to get this working, cant someone point me in the right direction? If i put the the values without promting it works buut when i do this i get error.

```
username1 = raw_input('Enter Username:\n')
password = raw_input('Enter Password:\n')
r = requests.get("https://linktoasp.net/",auth=HttpNtlmAuth("domain\\%s",password),cookies=jar) % (username1)
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "attend_punch.py", line 32,
>   in
>
> ```
> r = requests.get("https://linktoasp.netserver/homeportal/default.aspx",auth=HttpNtlmAuth("domain\\%r",password),cookies=jar)
> ```
>
> % (username1)   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %:
>   'Response' and 'str'

Comment: You want to do the % immediately following the string, you are trying to do it on the whole Request object right now.

Comment: i understand what you mean thanks guys

Comment: `%` in this code is acting like the Modulus operator---finding the remainder of the floor division.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this instead

```
auth = HttpNtlmAuth("domain\\%s" % username1, password), cookies = jar)
```

Answer (score 3):

What you probably want is:

```
r = requests.get(
        "https://linktoasp.net/",
         auth=HttpNtlmAuth("domain\\%s" % username1,password),cookies=jar)
```

In order to do string interpolation with `%`, the `%` and the value need to immediately follow the string:

```
"domain\\%s" % username1
```

rather than just coming later in the line:

```
HttpNtlmAuth("domain\\%s", ...) % username1
```

Answer (score 3):

The `%` symbol can have 2 meanings in Python:

- The modulo operator which will give you the remainder of the division of an int by the other. That is usually used for 2 numbers.
- The string formatting operator which comes after a string to replace the placeholders with actual values. That's what you want, but you are not placing it right after the string, so Python interprets it as the modulo operator, and since it's not defined for any object (only for `int` *usually*), raises that exception.